# NTP active but system clock not syncronized

Tags: 20.04, time, clock

I am trying to synchronize my system clock on ubuntu 20.04. But on running `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` I am finding the error as "Timed out waiting for reply from 192.46.211.253:123 (0.in.pool.ntp.org).". How can I sync my system clock ?

These are my credentials from `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check Firewall or Try changing pool server, https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/NTPPoolServers They could be blocked by ISP. BTW, Please copy/paste console test, screenshot are heavy and no way to search through them.

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me (using the NTP servers of my hoster):

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`

```
[Time]
NTP=ntp.yourhosters_ntp_url_1.tld
FallbackNTP=ntp.yourhosters_ntp_url_2.tld
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

Save and exit and then restart the NTP service: `sudo timedatectl set-ntp off` and then `sudo timedatectl set-ntp on`.

Now check with `timedatectl`. Output should be:

```
System clock synchronized: yes
NTP service: active
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this?

`sudo timedatectl set-ntp on`

Comment: This just activates the NTP service which is already active.