# System clock not synchronized but NTP service is active

Tags: 22.04, sync, time, ntp

I am unable to get a "yes" for "System clock synchronized" on my VPS (Ubuntu 22.04). The NTP service is active. I already tried `sudo timedatectl set-ntp on` but this only activates the NTP service and this was already running. So, what can I do to get the system clock synchronized?

My current output:

```
Local time: Fri 2023-02-17 15:18:46 CET
Universal time: Fri 2023-02-17 14:18:46 UTC
RTC time: Fri 2023-02-17 14:18:46
Time zone: Europe/Amsterdam (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: no
NTP service: active
RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416340/ntp-active-but-system-clock-not-syncronized) answer your question?

Comment: Are you using _ntp_, _chrony_, or _systemd-timesyncd_? Please, run the command `echo ntp chrony systemd-timesyncd | xargs -n 1 systemctl status` and [edit] your question to paste the output produced.